Rails fragment caching error in logs: Couldn't find template for digesting: news/new
I have a very simple rails view section I am applying fragment caching on and I am receiving this error in server logs, no matter what.
Sample code from view file:
  - cache ['v1'] do
    %p Hello World

Error in server log:
  Couldn't find template for digesting: news/new
  Couldn't find template for digesting: news/new
  Couldn't find template for digesting: news/new
Read fragment views/home/dashboard/_dashboard_right_components:6e9ed1a420727cad3e0098d33907b18c/v2 (16.5ms)
Write fragment views/home/dashboard/_dashboard_right_components:6e9ed1a420727cad3e0098d33907b18c/v2 (0.9ms)

I am on latest rails 6 (6.1.7.8) and using Memcached. This same behaviour is happening no matter the complexity of the view fragment.
NOTE - This error only appears in logs during the cache write. Once write is done error doesn't appear anymore. And on the user end (UI end), everything seems to work just fine. No errors on screen.

The error in logs appear due to usage of view_component gem. View component doesn't seem to be ready for well integrated rails fragment caching yet. More on this here - https://github.com/ViewComponent/view_component/issues/234
